# Script .bat para duplicar las lineas de uno o más archivos CSV

Tags: archivo, csv, cmd, batch, windows10

Los archivos **CSV** que serán elaborados no tendrán un header y su delimitador es el símbolo **“|”**

**Ejemplo:**

Si tengo un archivo **CSV** con nombre **“File.csv”** con los siguientes datos:

```
1000 | 1100 | 1200 | 1300 
2000 | 2100 | 2200 | 2300
3000 | 3100 | 3200 | 3300
```

El script me tiene que generar a partir del **File.csv** otro file con nombre **“File_Modificado.csv”** con los siguientes datos:

```
1000 | 1100 | 1200  | 1300 
1000 | 1100 | -1200 | 1300 
2000 | 2100 | 2200  | 2300
2000 | 2100 | -2200 | 2300
3000 | 3100 | 3200  | 3300
3000 | 3100 | -3200 | 3300
```

- Tiene que duplicar cada fila.
- La fila duplicada ira después de la fila original.
- El dato de la penúltima columna dela fila duplicada tiene que ser negativo.

**Otras funciones:**

- El script se encontrara en una carpeta donde elaborara todo los archivos .csv que se encuentre en esta.
- El script tiene que aceptar cualquier file con extensión csv sin importar que nombre tenga.
- Los files.csv generados tienen que ir en una nueva carpeta “Modified Files”

**Mi código:**

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


for /f "usebackq tokens=1-7 delims=^|" %%a in ("File.csv") do (
      echo %%a%%b %%c %%d %%e -%%f %%g) >> File_Modificado.csv
```

**Mi resultado:**

```
1000  1100 -1200 1300 
2000  2100 -2200 2300
3000  3100 -3200 3300
1000  1100 -1200 1300 
2000  2100 -2200 2300
3000  3100 -3200 3300
```

- Los datos no salen como quiero y **falta el delimitador**.

Answer (score 0):

mirando el código que escribiste pensé que lo mejor era usar como delimitador los espacios en blanco para que imprima los | a través de un parámetro.

También quité la línea de setlocal porque no la vi necesaria al no trabajar con variables.

Y por último pensé que la forma más fácil de hacer lo que querías es duplicado la línea del `ECHO` y poniéndo un signo **-** en el parámetro que corresponda.

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR /F "tokens=1-7" %%a IN (File.csv) DO (
    ECHO %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g >> File_Modificado.csv
    ECHO %%a %%b %%c %%d -%%e %%f %%g >> File_Modificado.csv
)
:: %%b, %%d y %%f se corresponden con el carácter "|"
```